# Accessing variable from a def when declared from a proc

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

I have something like this:

```
@menus = { Yay: '/', Yay2: '/yay2' }

@menus.each do |title, link|
  get link do
    erb title.downcase
  end
end

def foo
  'test' + @menus.join(', ')
end
```

the yay.erb or yay2.erb contains:

```
<%= foo %>
```

it shows error that method `@menus` in `foo` is a `nil` object because the `get link` declared inside a proc, how to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `@menus` there is an instance variable of the class, whereas in the method it is referring to an instance variable of the instance—which is different.

Make `@menus` a local variable so it will be closed over, then use `define_method` instead of `def` so your method definition is a closure and `menus` is accessible from it:

```
menus = { Yay: '/', Yay2: '/yay2' }

menus.each do |title,link|
  get link do
    erb title.downcase
  end
end

define_method :foo do
  'test' + menus.join(', ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Hashes do not have a join() method.

2) Apparently the code you posted is inside a class, so another solution is to provide an accessor method for the *class instance variable* you created named @menus, and then instead of writing @menus you would write self.class.menus:

```
class SomeClass
  #Inside here and outside of any def's self=SomeClass

  class <<self           #Open the class's singleton class
    attr_reader :menus
  end

  @menus = { Yay: '/', Yay2: '/yay2' }  #@menus attaches to self, which is SomeClass

  @menus.each do |title, link|  #@menus is retrieved from whatever object self is, which is SomeClass
    puts title, link
  end

  def foo
     #Inside here self=the instance of SomeClass that called this method, 
     #so @menus will be retrieved from that instance--not SomeClass
    'test ' + self.class.menus.keys.join(', ')
  end

end
```

Instance variables, i.e. those starting with @, attach themselves to whatever self is or are retrieved from whatever self is.